# Android: set one Button to do several things

Tags: android

Can anyone help me? I'm stuck on this thing for about week. I want to set one button to do several things. For example: when I pressed button once - b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a), when I pressed twice - b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.b), when pressed third - b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.c) and so on. It is possible to do this? Very thanks!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    b1.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have an int counter defined. In the `onClick` increment it and do whatever you want based on it's value

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible 
use button property known as setTag and getTag. It work same as that of flag

Example:

```
      b1.setTag("1");
        b1.setOnClickListener(
        new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
             if b1.getTag().equals("1"){
             b1.setTag("2")

            }
            else if(b1.getTag().equals("2")) {} 
            }
        }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a recent tutorial, detailing and explaining how to do what you want but it is accomplished using a short and long button press.
Try this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUgL8b7M8ns
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable

```
private int index = 0;
```

Then in your code do this

```
b1.setOnClickListener(
        new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                switch (index) {
                    case 0:
                        firstFunction();
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        secondFunction();
                        break;
                }

                // Advance your counter and extract the % 
                index++;  
                index = index % numOfDifferentFunctions; 
            }
        }
);
```